# Sorting a Hash of Array of Hashes by Internal Hash Value

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this, and I'm sure it's just a case of be being dense today.  I have a data structure similar to this:

```
{
  PDGFRA => [
    { "p.N659K" => 22 },
    { "p.D842Y" => 11 },
    { "p.I843_S847>T" => 9 },
    { "p.D842_H845del" => 35 },
    { "p.I843_D846delIMHD" => 24 },
    { "p.I843_D846del" => 21 },
    { "p.D842V" => 457 },
    { "p.N659Y" => 5 },
    { "p.M844_S847del" => 7 },
    { "p.S566_E571>K" => 8 },
    { "p.S566_E571>R" => 50 },
    { "p.V561D" => 54 },
  ],
}
```

I would like to print out the results, reverse sorted (greatest to smallest) by the hash values, so ultimately I end up with something like this

```
PDGFRA    p.D842V    457
PDGFRA    p.V561D    54
PDGFRA    p.S566_E571>R    50
PDGFRA    p.D842_H845del    35
.
.
.
etc.
```

I have no problem printing the data structure as I want, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort the data prior to printing it out.  I've tried to sort like this:

```
for my $gene ( sort keys %matches ) {
    for my $var ( sort { $a->{$var} <=> $b->{$var} } @{$matches{$gene}} {
        print "$var\n";
    }
 }
```

But whether I use `$var` or `$_` it doesn't seem to work, complaining that '$var' is not defined, and '$_' is not initialized.  I also tried (really pathetically!) to use a Schwarzian transform, but I don't think I'm even close on this one:

```
for my $gene ( sort keys %matches ) {
    my @sorted = 
        map { $_->[0] } 
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
        map { [ $_, $matches{$gene}->{$_} ] } @{$matches{$gene}};
}
```

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction for sorting a hash or arrays of hashes by internal hash value?

Comment: All the hash-refs in the array ref are only going to contain 1 key? But it's a different key for each hash-ref ? It's just a weird data structure not very conducive to traversal (or sorting for that matter)... easy enough to deal with though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$VAR` above is `Data::Dumper::Dumper(\%matches)` ...

If you don't want to make your data-structure nicer....

```
for my $gene ( sort keys %matches ) {
    for my $hash ( sort { 
                      my ($akey) = keys %$a;
                      my ($bkey) = keys %$b;
                      $a->{$akey} <=> $b->{$bkey} 
                   } @{$matches{$gene}} ) {
        my ($key) = keys %$hash;
        print "$key => $hash->{$key}\n";
    }
}
```

That sorts by the value (e.g: 12) not the key (e.g: 'p.I843_D846del'). I figured since you used a numeric comparison that you'd want to sort by the numeric value ;-)

**edited:** fixed body of inner loop.

**edit 2:**

I see you tried a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)... if you keep your data-structure as is, that might be a more efficient solution... as follows:

```
for my $gene ( sort keys %matches ) {
    print "$_->[0] => $_->[1]\n" for                     # print both key and value
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }                     # sort by value (e.g: 35)
        map { my ($key) = keys %$_; [$key, $_->{$key}] } # e.g:['p.D842_H845del' ,35]
        @{$matches{$gene}};
}
```

---

But instead, I'd just fix the data structure.

Probably just make both the 'key' (e.g: 'p.I843_D846del') and the 'value' (e.g: 12) both values and give them consistent key names.

Comment: Yeah, I think you might be right - I might consider a different data structure.  I went with keys in order to get the count data (this is from a much, larger and more complex data set).  But this sort is definitely not pretty.  I changed the sort order in your code to go from greatest to least, and there is a missing parenthesis right before `@{$matches{$gene}}`, but the code otherwise does work quite well!  Not sure a better way to wrangle this data, but I think this should work OK for now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Just saw the ST method. That's actually a little better still.  I think I see where I was going wrong when building the original structure to pass to the sort part of the transform.  This is extremely helpful; thanks again!  I also forgot to mention one more typo in the first method: we need to dereference the hash, so the line should be `print "$key => $hash->{$key}\n"'`

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed. (I should actually try code before posting it!)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative. This one works by sorting a list of *indices* into the array `@sorted` so that you can then just iterate over an array slice `@$list[@sorted]`.

You're hampered by the data format though, and it's messy just to extract a pair of values given a single-element hash.

I hope this helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %matches = (
  PDGFRA => [
    { "p.N659K"            =>  22 },
    { "p.D842Y"            =>  11 },
    { "p.I843_S847>T"      =>   9 },
    { "p.D842_H845del"     =>  35 },
    { "p.I843_D846delIMHD" =>  24 },
    { "p.I843_D846del"     =>  21 },
    { "p.D842V"            => 457 },
    { "p.N659Y"            =>   5 },
    { "p.M844_S847del"     =>   7 },
    { "p.S566_E571>K"      =>   8 },
    { "p.S566_E571>R"      =>  50 },
    { "p.V561D"            =>  54 },
  ],
);

while (my ($key, $list) = each %matches) {

  my @sorted = sort {
    my ($ka, $va) = %{ $list->[$b] };
    my ($kb, $vb) = %{ $list->[$a] };
    $va <=> $vb;
  } 0 .. $#$list;

  for my $item (@$list[@sorted]) {
    printf "%s   %s     %d\n", $key, %$item;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
PDGFRA   p.D842V     457
PDGFRA   p.V561D     54
PDGFRA   p.S566_E571>R     50
PDGFRA   p.D842_H845del     35
PDGFRA   p.I843_D846delIMHD     24
PDGFRA   p.N659K     22
PDGFRA   p.I843_D846del     21
PDGFRA   p.D842Y     11
PDGFRA   p.I843_S847>T     9
PDGFRA   p.S566_E571>K     8
PDGFRA   p.M844_S847del     7
PDGFRA   p.N659Y     5
```

---

**Update**

In my comment on David W's answer I suggest a data structure that was just an array of two-element arrays, instead of an array of single-element hashes.

This is what that would look like. The output is identical to the above code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %matches = (
  PDGFRA => [
    [ "p.N659K",             22 ],
    [ "p.D842Y",             11 ],
    [ "p.I843_S847>T",        9 ],
    [ "p.D842_H845del",      35 ],
    [ "p.I843_D846delIMHD",  24 ],
    [ "p.I843_D846del",      21 ],
    [ "p.D842V",            457 ],
    [ "p.N659Y",              5 ],
    [ "p.M844_S847del",       7 ],
    [ "p.S566_E571>K",        8 ],
    [ "p.S566_E571>R",       50 ],
    [ "p.V561D",             54 ],
  ],
);

while (my ($key, $list) = each %matches) {

  my @sorted = sort { $list->[$b][1] <=> $list->[$a][1] } 0 .. $#$list;

  for my $item (@$list[@sorted]) {
    printf "%s   %s     %d\n", $key, @$item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful and informative!  Thank you for editing my OP too; I should have thought to use Data::Dump instead of Data::Dumper!

Comment: @drmrgd: You're welcome. `Data::Dump` is generally superior, but `Data::Dumper` has been a core module distributed with Perl 5 since version 005 so it has a far greater foothold. Also, my apolgies for a bug in my update code: I had `$b` twice when it should have been `$b` and `$a`.

Answer (score 2):

You've already accepted an answer, but I want to comment on your data structure. You have:

- A hash
- That hash contains an array.
- These arrays contain a hash that only has a single key in it.

Why the array which contains the hashes with only a single key? Why not simply get rid of the array?

```
$VAR1 = {
      'PDGFRA' =>  {
                      'p.N659K' => 22,
                      'p.D842Y' => 11,
                      'p.I843_S847>T' => 9,
                      'p.D842_H845del' => 35,
                      'p.I843_D846delIMHD' => 24,
                      'p.I843_D846del' => 21,
                      'p.D842V' => 457,
                      'p.N659Y' => 5,
                      'p.M844_S847del' => 7,
                      'p.S566_E571>K' => 8,
                      'p.S566_E571>R' => 50,
                      'p.V561D' => 54,
     };
```

This would greatly simplify your structure **and** make it easier to find the values enclosed in the inner most hash. You can access the keys directly.

If the problem is that some of these hash keys *may* be duplicates, you can make that hash key point to an array of values:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'PDGFRA' =>  {
                      'p.N659K' => 22,
                      'p.D842Y' => 11,
                      'p.I843_S847>T' => [
                                            6,
                                            9
                                          ],
                      'p.D842_H845del' => 35,
                      'p.I843_D846delIMHD' => 24,
                      'p.I843_D846del' => 21,
                       ...
```

Note that `p.I843_S847` contains both `6` and `9`. You could simplify and make each value of the inner hash a reference to an array, and 99% of those arrays may contain a single value, or you could detect with the [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/fucntions/ref.html) command whether the content is a scalar or a reference to an array. Either way, you still have the benefit of the faster lookup, and easier access to the keys in that hash, so you can sort them.

Since, you are familiar with using complex data structures in Perl, you should also learn about how [Object Oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) works. This will make it a lot easier to handle these structures, and will also help you in development because it gives you a clean way of relating to these complex structures.

Comment: Nice summary of the alternatives. It's my guess that the hashes are never accessed by key, so they may as well be two-element arrays.

Comment: Thank you both for very insightful answers!  I think both of you (actually all of your!) are correct and I overly complicated my data structure trying to not only fit all cases, but also 'one size fits all' for the anticipated use of the data downstream.  I think I'm going to rebuild the above data structure to the more simple case David W presented.  In what I showed, I am not really using the hash keys.  But, I will need them for other purposes in the script.  So, I think a HoH would definitely be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure appears to have unnecessary depth. But here's a Schwartzian Transform version that will sort it as you want.

```
for my $gene (sort keys %matches) {
    my @sorted = map  { {@$_} }                # Back to hash.
                 sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }  # Sort.
                 map  { [each %$_] }           # Unpack the 1-key hash.
                 @{$matches{$gene}};
}
```